# Pyplot set tick frequency and tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a plot with matplotlib where I want to specify both the position of the tick marks, and the text of the tick marks. I can individually do both with  `yticks(np.arange(0,1.1,1/16.))` and `gca().set_yticklabels(['1','2','3'])`. However, for some reason when I do both of them together, the labels do not appear on the graph. Is there a reason for this? How can I get around it? Below is a working example of what I want to accomplish.

```
x = [-1, -0.2, -0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 7.8, 7.85, 8.15, 8.2, 12]
y = [1, 1, 15/16., 15/16., 1, 1, 15/16., 15/16., 1, 1]

figure(1)
plot(x,y)
xlabel('Time (years)')
ylabel('Brightness')
yticks(np.arange(0,1.1,1/16.))
xticks(np.arange(0,13,2))
ylim(12/16.,16.5/16.)
xlim(-1,12)
gca().set_yticklabels(['12/16', '13/16', '14/16', '15/16', '16/16'])
show(block = False)
```

Effectively I just wanted to replace the numerical values with fractions, but when I run this, the labels do not appear. It seems that using both `yticks()` and `set_yticklabels` together is a problem because if I remove either line, the remaining line works as it should.

If anyone can indicate how to simply force the label to be a fraction, that would also solve my problem.

EDIT:
I found an ugly workaround by using

```
ylim(12/16., 16.5/16)
gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator([12/16., 13/16., 14/16., 15/16., 16/16.]))
gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(FixedFormatter(['12/16', '13/16', '14/16', '15/16', '16/16']))
```

While this may work for this specific example, it does not generalize well and it is cumbersome to specify the exact location and label of every tick mark. If anyone finds another solution, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your `arange` should produce 5 ticks, the same as labels you set.
`arange` is not good for that. It is better to use `linspace`.

2) You can set ticks and labels with the same function

```
plot(x,y)
xlabel('Time (years)')
ylabel('Brightness')
yticks(np.linspace(12/16., 1, 5), ('12/16', '13/16', '14/16', '15/16', '16/16') )
xticks(np.arange(0,13,2))
ylim(12/16.,16.5/16.)
xlim(-1,12)
```

[image]

3) Note that you should adjust the actual values of the axis with the position of the labels using `linspace(12/16., 1, 5)` instead of `arange(0, 1.1, 1/16.))`